# Pythonic way to check for a condition with a timeout?

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements, timeout

I need to check for a certain condition before a timeout. If the condition is met before the limit then I return `True`, otherwise I return `False`.

I'm doing this in the following way:

```
def foobar():
    counter = 1
    condition_met = False
    while counter < max_limit:
        if <conditions are met>:
            condition_met = True
            break
        time.sleep(10)
        counter += 1
    return condition_met
```

I'm wondering if there's a more pythonic way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

A really good way to time things is by using—*shock*—the `time` module:

```
import time

def foo():
    max_limit = 25  # Seconds.

    start = time.time()
    condition_met = False
    while time.time() - start < max_limit:
        if <conditions are met>:
            condition_met = True
            break
        time.sleep(10)

    return condition_met
```

See? The module is good for more than just `sleep`ing. `;¬)`

Comment: Thank you for this tip, it's better that computing a counter and increment it

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have a code in a function.
The below code get rid of a variable `condition_met` and `break` statement.

```
counter = 1
# condition_met = False
while counter < max_limit:
    if <conditions are met>:
        # condition_met = True
        return True   # get rid of break statement
    time.sleep(10)
    counter += 1
return False
```

Comment: You could save two more lines and a variable by just looping `for _ in range(max_limix):` (assuming `counter` is not used in the condition)

Comment: Thanks, indeed you're right but my bad i forgot to add that after the `while` I print a message whether conditions are met or we reach a timeout but checking condition_met value. Using your solution I'd need to do the check outside my function and at the end it'd almost be the same thing but I prefer yours because it removes a variable

Comment: @Simon  Instead of `True` and `False` you can return the message that you want to print.

Comment: True again but in my case I need to quit my program and print a Warning if False. So I still need to check the value returned.

Comment: Incrementing a counter isn't a very accurate way of timing something, it's just a count. In this case there is a relationship between elapsed time and loop iterations because of the `time.sleep()` call in the loop, but in general it will depend on how fast the computer can execute the other statements within the loop. To actually _time_ how long something is or has taken requires determining the amount of time that has elapsed since some starting point.

Answer (score 2):

If it were not for the `time.sleep`, your loop would be equivalent to

```
for _ in range(max_limit):
    if <condition>:
        return True
    # time.sleep(10)
return False
```

Which is equivalent to `return any(<condition> for _ in range(max_limit)`.

Thus, you could (ab)use `any` and `or` to check whether the condition is met up to a certai number of times while waiting a bit before each check:

```
any(time.sleep(10) or <condition> for _ in range(max_limit))
```

This will first evaluate `time.sleep`, which returns `None`, and then evaluate the condition, until the condition is met or the `range` is exhausted.

The only caveat is that this will call `time.sleep` even before the first check of the condition. To fix this, you can first check the counter variable and only if that is `> 0` call `time.sleep`:

```
any(i and time.sleep(10) or <condition> for i in range(10))
```

Whether that's clearer than the long loop is for you to decide.

---

As suggested [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53666027/python-way-to-check-for-a-condition-with-timeout/53666805?noredirect=1#comment96334449_53666805), you can in fact just invert the above `any` clause to

```
any(<condition> or time.sleep(10) for _ in range(max_limit))
```

This will first check the condition and only if the condition is false will `sleep`. It also ready much more naturally than any of the above two appraoches.

Comment: Thanks Tobias, I'm voiceless

Comment: @Simon I am very sorry to hear that. Or did you mean speechless? ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't the first solution already work if rewritten as `any(<condition> or time.sleep(10) for _ in range(max_limit))`?

Comment: @lekv Absolutely, and it also ready much more naturally. Makes me wonder why I missed that. Thanks! (I _think_ I thought "hm, but we don't know if <condition> will be true or false, so we can't put the `or` after or it may not be evaluated", but of course that's just how we want it.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it that uses a [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer) in conjunction with a function decorator to know when a given time limit has been exceeded.

I adapted the approach in @Aaron Hall's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31667005/355230) to a very similar [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call) question so it can be used without killing the main thread (i.e. the caller) in the process.

In this scheme, a `Timer` object is created to call a `quit` function after a `time_limit` number of seconds has elapsed. If that happens the `quit` function prints out a notification message and then causes a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception to be raised by calling [`_thread.interrupt_main()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html#_thread.interrupt_main). The `decorator()` function wrapped around the original function catches this exception and makes it appear that the function returned `False` — conversely, if that doesn't happen, it cancels the `Timer` thread and returns `True`.

```
from random import randint
import sys
import time
import threading
import _thread as thread  # Low-level threading API


def interupt_after(time_limit):
    ''' Decorator to raise KeyboardInterrupt if function takes more than
        `time_limit` seconds to execute.
    '''
    def quit_func(func_name):
        print('{0}() took too long'.format(func_name), file=sys.stderr)
        sys.stderr.flush()
        thread.interrupt_main()  # Raises KeyboardInterrupt.

    def decorator(func):
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            timer = threading.Timer(time_limit, quit_func, args=[func.__name__])
            timer.start()
            try:
                func(*args, **kwargs)  # Note return value ignored.
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                return False
            finally:
                timer.cancel()
            return True
        return decorated

    return decorator


if __name__ == '__main__':

    @interupt_after(5)
    def foo(lo, hi):
        mid = (lo+hi) // 2
        condition_met = False
        while not condition_met:
            if randint(lo, hi) == mid:  # Condition to meet.
                condition_met = True
                break
            time.sleep(1)

        return condition_met

    print(f'foo(40, 44):', foo(40, 44))
    print('-fini-')
```

It prints this when the condition is met in the allotted time:

```
foo(40, 44): True
-fini-
```

and this when it's not:

```
foo() took too long
foo(40, 44): False
-fini-
```